# How to convert basic php mysql blog url with post title included

Tags: php

For example:

Currently my blog page url id:
`mydomain.com/index.php?id=2`.

Instead of this I want it as
mydomain.com/posttitle/  (similar to wordpress post url) as I am a new this.

Comment: Search for ***routes***.

Comment: You need to do using htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess file to eliminate index.php and rewrite URL to make it like wordpress URL.

You may get help from this link https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php